# Codeigniter function delete not working online only on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with delete function online. On localhost everything works perfectly.
Maybe is something wrong I don't know.

Model code:

```
    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('formular');  
        redirect('/site/cautare/');
    }
```

Controller code

```
    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('delete_model');
        $this->delete_model->delete($id);
    }
```

View code from where I make the deletion

```
<?php $del =  (site_url().'/site/delete/'.$row->id) ?>
<a href="<?php echo $del ?>" class="delfisa" onclick="return confirm('Are u Sure?')">Delete</a>
```

Url is base64_encoded. When I click the delete button I get:

http://exemplesite.info/index.php/site/delete/id_number - a blank page with no errors

It seems to me that function is blocked at controller.

Comment: what is the error message you are receiving? from Apache logs or increase CI log level

Comment: what is the error and try to echo  site_url().'/site/delete/'.$row->id  to debug the value/page redirection url

Answer (score 1):

your code is right.sometimes function name causes problem.Try to change the function name as delete is a CI keyword.

in controller code

```
function delete_record($id)
{
    $this->load->model('delete_model');
    $this->delete_model->delete_record($id);
}
```

in model

```
function delete_record($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('formular');  
    redirect('/site/cautare/');
}
```

may be this will work.change the function name and try.

Answer (score 0):

is it right to redirect directly from model ?

I would do it this way:

Model code:

```
function delete($id){
   $this->db->where("id",$id);
   $this->db->delete("formular");
}
```

Controller:

```
function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('delete_model');
    $this->delete_model->delete($id);
    redirect('/site/cautare/');
}
```

I hope i could help.

Comment: I've made the change. Still having the same problem. I could even take out redirect, is not really necessary.

Comment: Could you post content of cautare Method (arguments and body) ?

Answer (score 0):

Models are for data only either return a standard result such as an key/value object or a boolean.

all logic should be handled / controlled by the Controller.

Models are not page specific, and are used globally throughout the whole application, so if another class / method uses the model, it might get redirect to the incorrect location as its a different part of your site.

you should make your redirect in controller method.

So put this in controller instead model

```
redirect('/site/cautare/');
```

Comment: I've made the change. Still having the same problem. I even took out redirect, is not really necessary, but still not working online.